# Functional Analysis - Finding the multiplicative operator norm over L1

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in C([0,1])$, the space of continuous real-valued functions over $[0,1]$.

Let $\Gamma_f: L^1([0,1],m) \rightarrow  L^1([0,1],m)$, the space of complex-valued functions Lebesgue integrable functions over $[0,1]$, given by $\Gamma_f(g) = fg$ (when we speak of space, it is really the equivalence classes of functions equal almost everywhere - as their integrals are preserved, and we wish to define a proper norm on $L^1$).

The norm on $L^1$ is given by $\|g\|_1 = \int_0^1 |g| \,dm$.

I have shown that $\|\Gamma_f(g)\|_1 = \|fg\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f||g| \,dm \leq \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_1$.

Therefore for all $g \in L^1([0,1])\setminus \{0\}$, $\dfrac{\|\Gamma_f(g)\|_1}{\|g\|_1} \leq \|f\|_\infty$, where $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ is the supremum norm.

Thus $\|\Gamma_f\|\leq \|f\|_\infty$, where $\| \cdot \|$ is the operator norm on $\mathcal L (L^1([0,1],m))$

**Question: Prove equality: $\|\Gamma_f\| =  \|f\|_\infty$**

I understand that we can simply focus on nonnegative functions since the $L^1$ norm involves only those. Now, I can find a measurable $g$ to make $\|fg\|_1$ any number I like within $\epsilon$, but this is not impressive since it only uses $f$'s continuity, and not its supremum.  I was thinking it might not be possible to provide an explicit $g$ such that $\int_0^1 |fg| = \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_1$, but if I can get sufficiently close. I was thinking to use the fact that the $L^p$ norms converge to the sup norm, but it didn't quite pan out.

Ideas??

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Can't you find a $g\in L^1$ with $\lVert fg\rVert_1 \geqslant (\lVert f\rVert_\infty - \varepsilon)\lVert g\rVert_1$ for any given $\varepsilon > 0$?

Comment: That, for some reason, is much easier said than done. Can you say more? (thanks for catching that typo btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$.

You want to "concentrate" as much as possible of $g$ near the maximum of $f$. Suppose that $f(t_0)=\max\{f(t):\ t\in[0,1]\}$. By continuity, we can choose $\delta>0$ with $f(t)>f(t_0)-\varepsilon$ for $t\in(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$. Let $g=1_{(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)}$. Then
$$
\int_0^1fg=\int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta}f>(f(t_0)-\varepsilon)2\delta=(\|f\|_\infty-\varepsilon)\,\|g\|_1.
$$

Comment: That's wonderful; thanks!  This is the same style trick that is done in proving that $\left ( \int_0^1 |f|^n \right )^{1/n} \rightarrow \|f\|_\infty$ for continuous $f$.  I will try not to forget this.  Thanks!